# External Monitor Not Working Fedora 37

Tags: fedora, usb, nvidia, multi-monitor, displayport

I am using Fedora 37 and for some reason my external monitor is not working. I have a USB-C display port directly connected to my NVIDIA graphics card (as far as I can tell). The graphics card appears to be working fine (`nvidia-smi` looks normal).

The monitor gets detected but the computer still will not display too it

At first I thought it was a wayland issue and I tried the suggestion [here](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/cant-detect-external-monitor-on-fedora-31/61058) which worked for another user on Fedora 31, restarted and logged in with Xorg, but it did not work for me.

I noticed dmesg

```
ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: UCSI_GET_PDOS failed (-95)
```

I havent found a solution for this

Also when I go to settings and try to change the monitor resolution, the whole screen dims and I cant interact with any menus, its almost like it thinks the primary monitor is the secondary monitor.

Also the resolution for the secondary monitor , *I think* is set too high. Closer too that of my primary monitor.

How can I make Fedora 37 render correctly too my secondary monitor?

The monitor by the way is an old VGA display but it has a VGA-display port adapter

Comment: [Latest proprietary NVIDIA drivers?](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2460560.html) [`fwupdmgr`?](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/usb-c-and-hdmi-cable-plug-in-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-fedora-35/75075/4) [Blacklisting `usci-aspi` as a workaround?](https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1202386)

Comment: When I went to go try some of this, I found the latest update fixed the problem, however the screen flickers when I use the mouse sometimes